# VirtualBox Ubuntu 18.04 Installation Getting Stuck

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I am installing Ubuntu 18.04.2 on Virtual Box 5.2.10 however every time I select the option Erase disk and install Ubuntu It is getting hanged. I tried sevral time however I am not getting the screen to select the timezone.

I am following this wiki page
https://www.wikihow.com/Install-Ubuntu-on-VirtualBox

can someone help me with this.

Comment: Try with other Ubuntu flavours. Check if same issue occurs.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply I have managed to resolve the issue I increased the size of the memory for Virtual Server to 2 GB and then installation completed. Thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

When researching I came across a article which stated problem starting Specific Ubuntu Version on VirtualBox and in the solution some one mentioned to increase the Memory so I thought this could be causing the issue during the installation too I increasing the size of memory to 2 GB from 1 GB when creating the server and the installation was completed successfully.